# Создание относительного пути у ярлыка к html файлу

Tags: html

есть группа папок внутри которых есть html файл. Есть ярлык на определенный html и размещен вне папок. Это все архивировано и выложена на сайте.
Скачавший архив,после распаковки, открывает ярлык, чтобы не искать среди кучи html.
**Вопрос:**
Как задать поля <Рабочая папка> и <Объект> у ярлыка, чтобы он работал у любого скачавшего?

Comment: Дика извиняюсь, а зачем такие трудности?

Answer (score 1):

Подробное [описание решения](https://sumtips.com/how-to/create-shortcut-with-relative-path-in-windows/) в Сети есть (и много). Но есть минусы - все это для Windows, причем в разных версиях решения могут различаться.

С другой стороны, в Вашем-то случае запускается не программа, а файл HTML, для которого относительные ссылки являются "родными" по природе. Сделайте вне папок не ярлык, а еще один HTML файл с заметным и понятным именем (например index.html или readme.html), разместите в нем приветствие и приглашение открыть основной файл по приведённой ниже ссылке или даже кнопке. Пользователю будет удобно.